# apt-get installation prblem

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apt-get

when i install any package in kali linux 2019.2 it happens some error..

root@kali:~# apt-get install vlc

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going
to be installed
Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going
to be installed
Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be
installed
Recommends: linux-image but it is not installable

#how can i fixed this error!

Comment: have you tried executing `apt --fix-broken install` as it says? if so, which was the result?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's a programming question, so it's off-topic here. 
See [What can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask].
Try https://unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to use `apt install -f`

Comment: apt --fix-broken install vlc ,
apt install -f vlc , in this two command this every time result is same....


virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed Recommends: linux-image but it is not installable